# JList value changes when clicked

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlist

New to the forum and to Java.  I am trying to have my JList respond when double-clicked, which I have accomplished.  The JList is being populated by a SQL query which is ran when a button in the GUI is pressed.  Based on the SQL query, the JList is populated, this is also working.

The issue comes about if I try to update the JList by clicking the button to query SQL again.  When I click that, the change initially shows up in the JList, however when I click on that option in the JList it immediately switches back to what it was initially.  When I double-click on what appears to be the incorrect name, the value that I have printing in the console reports correctly.  So it has the value correct in the console but the rendering in the JList is not correct.

I appreciate any responses, I have combed the forums without any luck.  I am new to Java so I'm sure there is quite a bit that isn't perfect with my code.  Code is below please let me know if you need more.  Thank you.

```
 public JPanel results(StringBuilder message)
{   
    StringBuilder[] options = {message};
    showOption = new JList(options);
    showOption.setLocation(300, 50);
    showOption.setSize(140,100);
    showOption.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    textPanel.add(showOption);
    showOption.revalidate();
    showOption.repaint();

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    //JList showOption = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();

    if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {

    int index = showOption.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
    Object o = showOption.getModel().getElementAt(index);
    System.out.println("Double-clicked on: " + o.toString());
    }
    }
    };

    showOption.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
    return totalGUI;
}
public static void main ( String args[] )
{
    //JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JTextField of Dreams [=]");

    GUI_TextField demo = new GUI_TextField();
    frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());
    //frame.setContentPane(demo.results(message));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(510, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things jump out at me immediately.

1. You're creating a new `JList` each time
2. You're manually setting the size and position of the `JList`
3. You're not removing the previous `JList`

For example...

```
public JPanel results(StringBuilder message)
{   
    StringBuilder[] options = {message};
    // Create new JList
    showOption = new JList(options);
    // This is ill advised
    showOption.setLocation(300, 50);
    showOption.setSize(140,100);
    showOption.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    // What about the last JList?
    textPanel.add(showOption);
```

This raises a number of possibilities, the likely one is that you are covering over the previous list, which is being brought to the front when `textPanel` is validated and painted.

Swing follows (loosly) the [MVC paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (and [for more details](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/understanding-model-view-controller.html))

So instead of re-creating the view each time, you should simply re-create the model, for example...

```
 public JPanel results(StringBuilder message)
 {   
     DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
     model.addElement(message);
     showOption.setModel(model);
```

If `showOption` isn't created initially before this method is called, you should consider putting in a `if` statement to detect when `showOption` is `null` and initialise it appropriately.

You should also avoid using `setLocation` and `setSize`.  Swing has being designed to operate with the use of layout managers, these make it possible to define workflow and general layout that can be used across multiple platforms.

Take a look at [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Thanks!  Your info helped me solve this.  I appreciate the example and the links.  I am just getting going with Java and this helped a lot.  Thanks again.